# OperationalError when connecting to Heroku Postgres database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, heroku

I have an app on Heroku which stores information in a Postgres database (Heroku Postgres :: Purple Crane). I often connect to this database pythonicly via python [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/). Lately, my psycopg connection gives an error:

```
OperationalError: could not translate host name "ec2-**-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known
```

Things I've done & know:

- verified the login credentials
- can connect and execute SQL queries via pg_admin3
- the app is up an running. no problems

I'm at a loss, so any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: **UPDATE:** I'm able to connect to my Postgres DB, using psycopg2, from another computer. Also, not able to ping "google.com", instance from the server, where psycopy2 is not working. So it seems the problem here is really about access to the internet and nothing inherit about my DB setup/configuration or interaction with psycopg2.

Comment: *"could not translate host name <host> to address: Name or service not known"* sounds like a DNS issue. Your update about not being able to ping `google.com` reinforces that suspicion.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165076/occasional-postgres-error-on-heroku-could-not-translate-host-name-pg-url-to) and the answer to it. You might have to contact Heroku support about that.