# "Could not translate host name" when connecting to the database on a ruby script

Tags: ruby, heroku

I am trying to access a database from a ruby script. Currently I have this code:

```
  config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.join("config","database.yml"))).result)
  environment = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
  return PGconn.connect( :hostaddr=>config[environment]["host"], :port=>config[environment]["port"], :dbname=>config[environment]["database"], :user=>config[environment]["username"], :password=>config[environment]["password"]);
```

My database.yml is the following:

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: usrname
  password: passwor
  database: dbname
  port: 5432

Then my script complained saying that:

> /app/scripts/crawler.rb:54:in `initialize': could not translate host
>   name "localhost" to address: Name or
>   service not known

I changed "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 and it worked.

When I upload to Heroku, I get the following:

> /app/scripts/crawler.rb:54:in `initialize': could not translate host
>   name "ec2-184-72-231-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or
>   service not known

Do I need to import some gem so it can translate the hostname to an IP? I've searched for it but there is not much information, the only thing I found was this similar but not the same question: [Occasional Postgres error on Heroku: could not translate host name "<pg URL>" to address: Name or service not known (PG::Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165076/occasional-postgres-error-on-heroku-could-not-translate-host-name-pg-url-to), but I don't know if the answer is the same, because I had the same issue on localhost and because his problem was occasional, while mine is not.

Thanks

Comment: Hi there, Can you help me in connecting heroku postres and my local machine postgres?

Answer (score 1):

It was a code problem, it should be :host instead of :hostaddr